# Ubuntu 14.04 Ethernet issue

Tags: 14.04

So I was running Ubuntu 12.10 until today I decided to upgrade since it is no longer supported. Now all of a sudden my Ethernet connection doesn't work and my computer is useless. In the top right corner of the screen the symbol looks as if the computer is searching for a wireless network. Also if it keeps telling me every couple of seconds that I was disconnected from the Internet and if I go to edit connected it always says the Ethernet was used just a couple of minutes ago. I'm not all that computer savvy so idk where to begin. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Ifconfig gives me...damn I gotta type this by hand on a cell phone...

Eth0 link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:b9:54:17:e1
Inet6 addr: fe80::21b:b9ff:fe54:17e1/64 Scope:Link
UPBROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets: 0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:47544 (47.5 KB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
Inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
Inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:10928 (10.9KB) TX bytes:10928 (10.9KB)

Ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 gives me...

Connect: Network is unreachable

And ping -c 4 Google.com reads...

Ping: Unknown host Google.com

And finally cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
```

Auto lo
Iface lo inet Loopback

Any ideas anyone? Really need to get my computer working thanks for the help

Comment: Begin by editing your post to include the output of `ifconfig` and `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c 4 google.com`. The output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

it seems your link is up but you do not have ip address.

Comment: That's giving me 
listening on LPF/eth0/00:1b:b9:54:17:e1
Sending on
LPF/eth0/00:1b:b9:54:17:e1
Sending on socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7ad3040b)

And that just keeps repeating at intervals and finally it says

No DHCPOFFERS RECEIVED
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.

Comment: Just went to the store and came back and all of a sudden everything is working fine...scared to restart the computer or anything cas I feel like it's gonna happen again

Comment: Never mind didn't even have to restart the computer it just stopped working on its own

Comment: Managed to grab this info while it was working though, is there a way to manually configure the connection using any of this?

IP address: 192.168.0.13
Broadcast address: 192.168.0.255
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default route: 192.168.0.1
Primary DNS: 209.18.47.61
Secondary DNS: 209.18.47.62

Comment: you can add that info to `/etc/network/interfaces`, but it is odd that it is not working via dhcp.  
If you want to give it a try, `sudo service networking stop` and add this to the file mentioned earlier:  
`auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.0.13  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
network 192.168.0.0  
broadcast 192.168.0.255  
gateway 192.168.0.1`    
You can see the interfaces file formatted correctly in this link [ www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/].
Then save,exit and execute `sudo service networking start`.

Answer (score 0):

So when I put the newer version of Linux on here earlier today it automatically made a connection called connection 1 or something like that and anyhow all I did was delete it and then click "auto Ethernet" and it works perfectly now...odd.